# Linux GUI development

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, gnome, kde-plasma

I have a large GUI project that I'd like to port to Linux.
What is the most recommended framework to utilize for GUI programming in Linux? Are Frameworks such as KDE / Gnome usable for this objective  Or is better to use something more generic other than X?

I feel like if I chose one of Gnome or KDE, I'm closing the market out for a chunk of the Linux market who have chosen one over the other.  (Yes I know there is overlap)

Is there a better way? Or would I have to create 2 complete GUI apps to have near 100% coverage?

It's not necessary to have a cross-platform solution that will also work on Win32.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your best bet may be to port it to a cross-platform widget library such as [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets), which would give you portability to any platform wxWidgets supports.

It's also important to make the distinction between Gnome libraries and GTK, and likewise KDE libraries and Qt. If you write the code to use GTK or Qt, it should work fine for users of any desktop environment, including less popular ones like XFCE. If you use other Gnome or KDE-specific libraries to do non-widget-related tasks, your app would be less portable between desktop environments.

Comment: I have used wxPython to implement GUIs.  Both Python & wxWidgets are portable across all the main platforms and with wxWidgets applications look "native".  Apparently (I've never tried it) PY2EXE works with wxPython.

Comment: 2 years on, I'm faced with the same problem as the OP; this is the first reasonably clear answer I read. Has anything changed in the meantime?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) or [Qt](http://www.trolltech.no/). They are both mature, well-structured and cross-platform, with decent documentation and sample source code.

Answer (score 4):

Gnome apps work on KDE desktops and vice versa; you won't be locking anyone out. As far as toolkits go, it's fairly subjective. All of the toolkits are fairly cross-platform. If you're not open source, then GTK+ would be the cheaper option, as Qt is only free for open source use, whereas GTK+ is LGPL.

Comment: Update: nowadays also Qt is LGPL: http://www.qtsoftware.com/about/licensing/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Indeed. It is a great improvement over the previous situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Mono? Programs like Paint.NET work great under Linux & Windows.