# GUI development In Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am working on application which need to develope in both windows and linux.
I am going to develop the GUI in MFC on windows.
I wanted what GUI available specific to Linux.
Any body suggest me API for the linux to develop the GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux GUI development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762/linux-gui-development)

Comment: why don't you use a croosplatform gui toolkit like GTK?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065693/gui-development-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/). It's modern, portable and object oriented. And it doesn't use a weird pre-compiler :)

Answer (score 2):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) is the best I think.

Comment: and it's portable, so you can (mostly) use the same code on Windows & Linux (and other OSes).

Comment: Qt show some time of problem of macro.like QOBJECT doesnot support ifndef(__linux) or #ifndef __WIN32

Comment: That's not actually true. Qt uses its own macros: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtglobal.html#Q_WS_X11

Answer (score 0):

Use Qt, available both on GNU/Linux and Windows. Easy to learn and use, and it have a very good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

GUIs which support several platforms:

- Qt https://www.qt.io/developers/
- GTK http://www.gtk.org/